# Covariant basis vectors and scale factors in toroidal coordinates

Tags: metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, covariance

The toroidal coordinate system $(\xi, \omega, \varphi)$ is defined in terms of the cylindrical coordinate system $(R, \phi, Z)$ as:

$$
R = \frac{{R_0' \sinh \xi}}{{\cosh \xi - \cos \omega}}, \\
Z = \frac{{R_0' \sin \omega}}{{\cosh \xi - \cos \omega}}, \\
\phi = \varphi.
$$

Given the position vector $\vec{r} = R\vec{e}_R + Z\vec{e}_Z + \phi\vec{e}_\phi$, and considering $(\xi, \omega, \varphi)=(x^1,x^2,x^3)$, I understand that the covariant basis vectors are

$$
\vec{e}_i=\frac{∂\vec{r}}{∂x^i}.
$$

I obtained:

$$
\vec{e}_1 =  \frac{{R_0' (1 - \cos \omega \cosh \xi)}}{{(\cosh \xi - \cos \omega)^2}} \vec{e}_R - \frac{{R_0' \sin \omega \sinh \xi}}{{(\cosh \xi - \cos \omega)^2}} \vec{e}_Z,
$$
$$
\vec{e}_2 = -\frac{{R_0' \sin \omega \sinh \xi}}{{(\cosh \xi - \cos \omega)^2}} \vec{e}_R + \frac{{R_0' (1 - \cos \omega \cosh \xi)}}{{(\cosh \xi - \cos \omega)^2}} \vec{e}_Z,
$$
$$
\vec{e}_3 = \vec{e}_\phi.
$$

Then, the components of the covariant metric tensor are $g_{ij} = \vec{e}_i \cdot \vec{e}_j$, and only the diagonal components are not zero due to the coordinate system being orthogonal. The scale factors are $h_i=\sqrt{g_{ii}}$, and I found:

$$
h_1 = h_2 = \frac{{R_0'}}{{\cosh \xi - \cos \omega}},
$$
$$
h_3=1.
$$

However, in the text I am reading, it is stated that:

$$
h_3 = \frac{{R_0'}}{{\cosh \xi - \cos \omega}} \sinh \xi.
$$

I do not understand what I am missing and I am sorry if I said something wrong or if it is something obvious. I am new to this and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your z coordinate is correct? wikipedia has a sin in the numerator, not sinh. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_coordinates

Comment: You are right, that was a typo; I edited the question to correct it.
But the following results I show here were derived with the right expression. I still do not understand how $h_3$ can be something other than what I have found.

Comment: Your $\phi$ unit vector should be something like $R \vec{e}_{\phi}$ (always check your units) and then you get the right answer. ie your $Rh_3=R = h_{\phi}$ in the wikipedia article.

Comment: I see what the issue is now. Thank you.